# How to Disable Session for one controller in dotnet core 3.1 webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, webapi

we are using app.UseSession() in our startup.cs, can we bypass session for one controller?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit, what is your concern about using Session middleware?

Comment: I don't want to use session middleware for one controller so session insertion is causing a bit overhead for it so want to remove it only for that controller to increase performance

Comment: Do you have any performance measurement? In my understanding ASP.NET Core sessions shouldn't cause any performance issues unless you use it in your controller explicitly

Comment: Yes we have tried disabling session by commenting app.UseSession() and we observed there was lot of improvement in terms of performance for that handler so I wanted to stop session insertion only for that handler

Comment: It's interesting. I've just tried to emulate a heavy session in my mvc app. Those controllers/actions that don't use session are working instantly without any impact. And controllers that interact with session somehow (e.g. read only one session value) have evident performance impact. Do you make any calls from your controller to other controllers where session is required?